# Parse through clicking Element collection by class in WatiN

Tags: c#, xpath, foreach, watin

I am using **WatiN** on this website: http://www.mcmaster.com/#socket-head-cap-screws/=k5c5q8
and I am trying to cycle through each page by clicking each of the h3 tags by it's class name. There is no href on the page, i believe the page uses javascript to load the next page when the h3 is clicked.

this is my code so far:

```
         types = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm']");
         foreach (HtmlNode type in types)
               {

                desc = type.InnerText.CleanText();

                browser.div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).Element(Find.ByClass("AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm")).Click();                        
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                types = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm']");
                doc2.LoadHtml(browser.Html);
                partTable = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='ItmTblGrp']");

                MineNext(doc, doc2, browser, typeUrl, types, desc, partTable);

                }
```

the most important line is

```
browser.div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).Element(Find.ByClass("AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm")).Click();
```

when i run this code, it clicks the first class of "AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm" but once i iterate back to this page, it tries to load the same element with the name of "Black-Oxide Alloy Steel" again. it will keep loading this over and over because it does not know how to differ the other H3s with the same class name. is there a way to do a **collection of these elements** and then run a **foreach loop** through the collection and click each one separate using **WatiN**?

Answer (score 1):

thank you everyone for not answering this question because it allowed me to figure it out for myself. giving me the greatest feeling ive felt at my job yet.

```
                   var h3s = browser.Div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).ElementsWithTag("h3").ToArray();
                    for (int i = 1; i < h3s.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        h3s[i].Click();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        types = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm']");
                        doc2.LoadHtml(browser.Html);
                        partTable = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='ItmTblGrp']");

                        MineNext(doc, doc2, browser, typeUrl, types, desc, partTable);
                        h3s = browser.Div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).ElementsWithTag("h3").ToArray();
                    }
```